# Android Eclipse View/Intent inquiry

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

So I'm taking a mobile programming class that's covering all 3 mobile OS's (android, iOS, WinMobile 8) and we haven't learned Java yet at all (it's mostly a game programming program, they are experimenting with mobile development now). So my question is basically I am trying to understand code that we are given as an example, so I'm going to post code below, and I'm only sure of what the code means up until I call a clickListener, I'm just trying to figure out what the code is doing so I can understand it. (We don't have any resource at our school for mobile development yet, this is the first class they are teaching on it). Thank you in advance and I appreciate any help given.

What I think this is doing:
-creating a link from Java to XML with "Button" and linking it to the id "button1"
-listening for a click

-when button is clicked:
-create a new intent (from my research 'intents' are glue between activities, though i'm still not sure what exactly this means) <-- this is where I am lost.

```
Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(myListener);

}

// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondPage.class);
        String text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
        myIntent.putExtra("Text", text);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); } };
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: My question was clearly stated. I'm just asking what the code from Intent to the end of the function means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a commented form of your code:

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
  // do something when the button is clicked
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // An intent tells the android system that you intend to start a new activity.
        // This can be done explicitly by giving the class object of the activity to be started
        // or it can be done implicitly by providing a string identifying the type
        // of action you wish to perform (like read a bar code).  In this case you are
        // explicitly stating that you wish to start the SecondPage intent.
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondPage.class);
        // get some text from an editText control in the current view
        String text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
        // Add that text as an extra bit of data to the Intent.  This will allow the
        // Activity that is started to read the extra bit of data.
        myIntent.putExtra("Text", text);
        // Start an activity with the given intent and tell the android system that you
        // are expecting some sort of result from the launched activity (like a barcode or an image)
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); } };
```

For information on the Intent, you can look at the javadoc, which states:

An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: That site is not much help trying to understand what it's doing in english, I have not taken any Java courses before this. Thanks anyways though. Do know that I don't just go to StackOverflow for every question I have, it's hard to find resources for android development, I did do due diligence before posting on here, (SO is a last resort option I like to figure things out for myself, if I can't I use SO). So yes, I did look at the javadoc before posting on here. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Updated with an annotated view of your source attempting to explain in plain english what is going on.

Comment: certainly. glad you found it more helpful.